# PyTorch - better way to get back original tensor order after torch.sort

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to get back the original tensor order after a `torch.sort` operation and some other modifications to the sorted tensor, so that the tensor is not anymore sorted. It is better to explain this with an example:

```
x = torch.tensor([30., 40., 20.])
ordered, indices = torch.sort(x)
# ordered is [20., 30., 40.]
# indices is [2, 0, 1]
ordered = torch.tanh(ordered) # it doesn't matter what operation is
final = original_order(ordered, indices) 
# final must be equal to torch.tanh(x)
```

I have implemented the function in this way:

```
def original_order(ordered, indices):
    z = torch.empty_like(ordered)
    for i in range(ordered.size(0)):
        z[indices[i]] = ordered[i]
    return z
```

Is there a better way to do this? In particular, it is possible to avoid the loop and compute the operation more efficiently?

In my case I have a tensor of size `torch.Size([B, N])` and I sort each of the `B` rows separately with a single call of `torch.sort`. So, I have to call `original_order` `B` times with another loop.

Any, more pytorch-ic, ideas?

**EDIT 1 - Get rid of inner loop**

I solved part of the problem by simply indexing z with indices in this way:

```
def original_order(ordered, indices):
    z = torch.empty_like(ordered)
    z[indices] = ordered
    return z
```

Now, I just have to understand how to avoid the outer loop on `B` dimension.

**EDIT 2 - Get rid of outer loop**

```
def original_order(ordered, indices, batch_size):
    # produce a vector to shift indices by lenght of the vector 
    # times the batch position
    add = torch.linspace(0, batch_size-1, batch_size) * indices.size(1)


    indices = indices + add.long().view(-1,1)

    # reduce tensor to single dimension. 
    # Now the indices take in consideration the new length
    long_ordered = ordered.view(-1)
    long_indices = indices.view(-1)

    # we are in the previous case with one dimensional vector
    z = torch.zeros_like(long_ordered).float()
    z[long_indices] = long_ordered

    # reshape to get back to the correct dimension
    return z.view(batch_size, -1)
```

Comment: This question is a special case for getting "inverse permutation". Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66838403/9758790), which also gave a solution with linear time complexity.

Answer (score 11):

```python
def original_order(ordered, indices):
    return ordered.gather(1, indices.argsort(1))
```

## Example

```python
original = torch.tensor([
    [20, 22, 24, 21],
    [12, 14, 10, 11],
    [34, 31, 30, 32]])
sorted, index = original.sort()
unsorted = sorted.gather(1, index.argsort(1))
assert(torch.all(original == unsorted))
```

## Why it works

For simplicity, imagine `t = [30, 10, 20]`, omitting tensor notation.

`t.sort()` gives us the sorted tensor `s = [10, 20, 30]`, as well as the sorting index `i = [1, 2, 0]` for free. `i` is in fact the output of `t.argsort()`.

`i` tells us how to go from `t` to `s`. "To sort `t` into `s`, take element 1, then 2, then 0, from `t`". Argsorting `i` gives us another sorting index `j = [2, 0, 1]`, which tells us how to go from `i` to the canonical sequence of natural numbers `[0, 1, 2]`, in effect reversing the sort. Another way to look at it is that `j` tells us how to go from `s` to `t`. "To sort `s` into `t`, take element 2, then 0, then 1, from `s`". Argsorting a sorting index gives us its "inverse index", going the other way.

Now that we have the inverse index, we dump that into `torch.gather()` with the correct `dim`, and that unsorts the tensor.

## Sources

[`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html#torch-gather)
[`torch.argsort`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.argsort.html#torch.argsort)

I couldn't find this exact solution when researching this problem, so I think this is an original answer.

Comment: This is elegant, but limited to sorting. In general cases (as in my cases), the index vector did not come from sorting. But I would still want to undo the ordering and go back to the original order.

Comment: @vega This is not true. `torch.argsort` gives the inverse permutation.  You can also refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66838403/9758790).