# How to quickly inverse a permutation by using PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, permutation, inverse

I am confused on how to quickly restore an array shuffled by a permutation.

**Example #1:**

- `[x, y, z]` shuffled by `P: [2, 0, 1]`, we will obtain `[z, x, y]`
- the corresponding inverse should be `P^-1: [1, 2, 0]`

**Example #2:**

- `[a, b, c, d, e, f]` shuffled by `P: [5, 2, 0, 1, 4, 3]`, then we will get `[f, c, a, b, e, d]`
- the corresponding inverse should be `P^-1: [2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 0]`

I wrote the following codes based on matrix multiplication (the transpose of permutation matrix is its inverse), but this approach is too slow when I utilize it on my model training. Does there exisits a faster implementation?

```py
import torch

n = 10
x = torch.Tensor(list(range(n)))
print('Original array', x)

random_perm_indices = torch.randperm(n).long()
perm_matrix = torch.eye(n)[random_perm_indices].t()
x = x[random_perm_indices]
print('Shuffled', x)

restore_indices = torch.Tensor(list(range(n))).view(n, 1)
restore_indices = perm_matrix.mm(restore_indices).view(n).long()
x = x[restore_indices]
print('Restored', x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I obtained the solution in [PyTorch Forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-quickly-inverse-a-permutation-by-using-pytorch/116205/2).

```
>>> import torch
>>> torch.__version__
'1.7.1'
>>> p1 = torch.tensor ([2, 0, 1])
>>> torch.argsort (p1)
tensor([1, 2, 0])
>>> p2 = torch.tensor ([5, 2, 0, 1, 4, 3])
>>> torch.argsort (p2)
tensor([2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 0])
```

**Update:**
The following solution is more efficient due to its linear time complexity:

```
def inverse_permutation(perm):
    inv = torch.empty_like(perm)
    inv[perm] = torch.arange(perm.size(0), device=perm.device)
    return inv
```