# How to invert the permutations in each row of a 2D Pytorch tensor without using for loop?

Tags: numpy, pytorch, tensor, combinatorics

Suppose I have a 2D tensor that contains a permutation in each row, for example

```
a = torch.tensor([[4, 3, 5, 0, 2, 1],
                  [5, 0, 3, 4, 2, 1],
                  [3, 1, 0, 2, 4, 5],
                  [5, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1],
                  [2, 4, 0, 1, 5, 3]])
```

I want to invert all the permutations in tensor `a` to get a tensor `b`. For example, after doing this operation on the above tensor `a` my desired output should be

```
>>> b
tensor([[3, 5, 4, 1, 0, 2],
        [1, 5, 4, 2, 3, 0],
        [2, 1, 3, 0, 4, 5],
        [1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 0],
        [2, 3, 0, 5, 1, 4]])
```

I tried to search online and found out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66838403/10786438) answer. How should I generalize the approach mentioned in that answer to invert all the permutations without using a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using [`torch.Tensor.scatter_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.scatter_.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_)

```
b = torch.zeros_like(a)
b.scatter_(1, a, torch.arange(a.size(1)).expand(a.size(0),-1))
```